# Doctrine Call to a member function %method% on null

Tags: doctrine

Помогите разобраться в одном моменте касаемо Doctrine.
К примеру у меня справочник продуктов и категории продуктов.

Я хочу отобразить все продукты и их категории если они есть. 
Выполняю запрос к базе и получаю следующий ошибку. Данная ошибка возникает потому что у некоторых продуктов поле `category_id равно null`.
Подскажите как правильно формировать такие запроса?

> **Error: Call to a member function getName() on null **

```
$Query= $em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p WHERE p.description = :desc')->setParameter('desc','Dark');

   $product= $Query->getResult(); 

    foreach ($product as  $value) {

        $test[$value->getName()] = $value->getCategory()->getName();

    }
```

Comment: А вы хотите получить все товары или только у которых есть категория? В первом случае достаточно проверки ```$value->getCategory()```, во втором можно сделать JOIN.

Comment: Я хочу получить все товары. Я пробовал использовать **empty** и **method_exists**, но также получал ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина в том, что у вас `$value->getCategory()` возвращает `null`, поэтому вам всего лишь надо добавить простую проверку:

```
$test[$value->getName()] = $value->getCategory() ? $value->getCategory()->getName() : '';
```